# date of birth field validate it empty or not using php

Tags: php

```
private function validatedateofbirth($ddd)
    {
          if(!isset($ddd) || empty($ddd))
          {
                   array_push($this->errorArray, Constants::$DateOfBirth);
                   return;

                }

    }


<?php echo $account->getError(Constants::$DateOfBirth); ?>
  <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="date_of_birth" value="<?php getInputValue('date_of_birth')?>">
```

dd-mm-yyyy how to check this empty or not?

Comment: *"how to check this empty or not?"* - well... `empty()` appropriately enough and that's what you seem to be using elsewhere; so what's not working? Are you checking for errors?

Comment: I think you want it - !empty($ddd) instead.

Comment: checking to input it or not! need to put value in it! thats i want! its not working properly!

Comment: when i input the error exist!

Answer (score 0):

Check all value's of your submit.

Check what data `$ddd` contains on a submit.

Check if `getInputValue('date_of_birth')` returns any value?